# Codename one calendar UpdateButtonDayDate() issue

Tags: java, android, sqlite, oop, codenameone

I am working on my project where I want to show when application starts then calendar display, which date contain events, for instance if the date contain events, then the day button contains * symbol and day, And if the date doesn't contain any event then it only displays a day.
I wrote following code, but it only displays * symbol when I am clicking on that button, So how can I manage this code that display * symbol on the date which only contain events when the application starts or that page gonna be loaded.

**Following is my code:-**

```
    public class Customised extends Calendar{
          ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
          int i,j,columns;



          @Override
          protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton,int currentMonth, int day) {
         dayButton.setText(""+day);



          dayButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {     
//Check which date having how many number of events===============================================================

          try{
              ShowEvent.removeAll();
          cur =  db.executeQuery("SELECT Event, Description from CalendarData  WHERE Date = ? ", dateLabel.getText());
          columns = cur.getColumnCount();
          if(columns > 0) {
          boolean next = cur.next();
          if(next) {               
          String[] columnNames = new String[columns];
          for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
          columnNames[iter] = cur.getColumnName(iter);
          }
          while(next) {
          Row currentRow = cur.getRow();
          String[] currentRowArray = new String[columns];
          for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
          currentRowArray[iter] = currentRow.getString(iter);
          }
          data.add(currentRowArray);
          next = cur.next();
          }
          Object[][] arr = new Object[data.size()][];
          data.toArray(arr);
          }
          }
          }catch(IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
          for(i = 0 ; i< data.size(); i++){
          Log.p(data.get(i)[0]);
          }

          Label a = new Label(dateLabel.getText());
          Label b = new Label("          "+i);
          Container container1 = TableLayout.encloseIn(2, a,b);
          container1.setUIID("container1");

          ShowEvent.add(container1);


              for( i = 0 ; i< data.size(); i++){
              for(j = 0; j<columns; j++){
          Log.p(data.get(i)[j]);
          SpanLabel spanData = new SpanLabel(data.get(i)[j]);
          spanData.setUIID("SpanLabel");
          ShowEvent.add(spanData);    
          }
          Label space = new Label("=======================");
          ShowEvent.add(space);
          Log.p("###################");
          }
          data.clear();

          if(i>0){
              if(Dialog.show("Choose action", "What you want to do?", "Add Events","View Events")){
                  calendar.show();
              }
                  else{
                  ShowEvent.show();
              }
          }else{
              Dialog.show("Add event","There is no event to display, Please add events first","OK","");

          }
//============================================================================================================
          } 
          });
          }

          @Override
          protected void initComponent(){
              ArrayList<String[]> data1 = new ArrayList<>();
              int k;
              Log.p("initComponent");

             try{
              cur = db.executeQuery("select Date from CalendarData");
              columns = cur.getColumnCount();
          if(columns > 0) {
          boolean next = cur.next();
          if(next) {               

          String[] columnNames = new String[columns];
          for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
          columnNames[iter] = cur.getColumnName(iter);
          }
          while(next) {
          Row currentRow = cur.getRow();
          String[] currentRowArray = new String[columns];
          for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
          currentRowArray[iter] = currentRow.getString(iter);
          }
          data1.add(currentRowArray);
          next = cur.next();
          }
          Object[][] arr = new Object[data1.size()][];
          data1.toArray(arr);
          }
          }
          }catch(IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
          for(k = 0 ; k< data1.size(); k++){
          Log.p(data1.get(k)[0]);

            }
          if(k>0){
              //cal.setUIID("CalendarSelectedDay");
          }

          }

          /*
          @Override
          protected boolean isInitialized(){
              boolean result = false;
              Log.p("isInitialised");
              return result;
          }*/

          public Customised(){

          }





          @Override
          protected Button createDay() {
          Button day = new Button();
          day.setAlignment(CENTER);
          day.setUIID("CalendarDay1");
          day.setEndsWith3Points(false);
          day.setTickerEnabled(false);
          return day;
          }



          }
```

**And the expected result will be:-**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's because you placed the code inside the actionPerformed method which is only triggered upon Button pressed/released.
Move your code to the updateButtonDayDate scope

Comment: When I copy that code in updateButtonDayDate scope, then it will get 'i' value 0. So it will not get into that if loop.

Comment: Can anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Update your question to show current state of your code if you are claiming that @Chen's suggestion is not working.  Looking at your existing code there are two big problems:  1) You are adding an action listener every time updateButtonDayDate() is called, and you don't appear to ever remove them, each button click will call multiple action listeners.  2) Your code to add the asterisk only runs when buttons are clicked.

Comment: And suppose if I am writing the same code in updateButtonDayDate () scope, then how can I access dayButton to change the button style dynamically or provide asterisk to the dayButton.

Comment: I assume you first show your UI and then you probably init your DB with data. if that's the case make sure you init your DB before you display the Calendar

Comment: No, I am overriding initComponent() method, So DB will be init first and then   UI gets initialize.

Comment: And also how can I compare both calendar date and database date? So application able to detect which date contains events.

Comment: Can you please explain with code that how to achieve this scenario by moving code to the updateButtonDayDate scope.